# While(false) causes unreachable statement compilation error

Tags: java, while-loop

I was recently removing a block of code from our code base before a release and used an if(false) statement to prevent execution:

```
if (false) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ...
}
```

This compiles fine and will prevent execution of the offending block of code (right or wrong, that's not the current argument).

However, kind of by accident, I changed the block above to:

```
while (false) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ...
}
```

and received an unreachable statement compilation error.

I appreciate the compilation error and understand the reasons, however, I'm struggling to comprehend the difference between the two blocks and why the former compiles fine but the latter does not when they both have unreachable statements.

Comment: My guess is that it's much easier to make a mistake involving `do-while` than with `if`. That should be why the latter case leads to an error.

Comment: My guess is that the original intent of the compiler author was to have both cause an unreachable error. However, because programming practice has people commonly disabling code with if(false), the allowed it as a special case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In both case the compiler should raise an error, because the code between braces is essentially pointless, **but** `if (false)` was kept in Java to simulate C/C++ preprocessor `#if 0`, quite a common way of disabling parts of code for testing or debugging.

EDIT: for reference, *"conditional compiling"* is detailed at the end of [chapter 14.21](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21) of the Java Language Specification.

Comment: Actually the programming practice of disabling code with if(false) predates the advent of C/C++ by a long shot.

Comment: Fair. But not the `unreachable statement error` part. Java architects should have decided: either report both as dead code at compile time or none. At least, they should have used a different, straightforward, syntax for simulating `#if 0`. For instance, `disabled {}` or something similar.

Comment: Yes, I agree. As I commented above, I bet originally both did cause the error and then they undid it for if(false) because programmers hated it. This would be a good candidate question to send to James Gosling.

Comment: @Stefano what's wrong with the behaviour? It flags the probable programmer error in the uncommon case, while allowing the common trick.

Comment: It does not simply flag (which would probably be fine), it throws a compilation error. I'm against this exception to the rule because of two main reasons. First, the Principle of Least Astonishment: if the compiler says it will catch and report unreachable statements, I would expect `javac` to actually catch and report **all** unreachable statements, no exceptions. Second, the block inside a `if (false) {}` is still parsed by the compiler, so any syntax error/incomplete stub inside will be reported; in C++, the compiler never sees a block wrapped by `#if 0`.

Answer (score 2):

"Java uses a simple flow analysis algorithm to find most common cases of unreachable code, and all such unreachable code blocks will be flagged as compile-time errors. That's why your "while (false) { ... }" statement produces an error.

However, Java makes a special exception for "if (false) { ... }", because programmers often use this construct during development to temporarily disable part of the program. That's why the compiler accepts this statement.

If you're interested in the nitty-gritty details, refer to the Java Language Specification's description of unreachable statements @ http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/#14.21."

Quoted from http://www.coderanch.com/t/266678/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/false-false